# Migrate SSIS packages using dtsconfig only - 2005 to 2017

Tags: ssis, ssis-2017

**UPDATE**

I tried the provided solution but still I am unable to upgrade the SSIS packages using just config file so that brings me to next question.

**Updated Question-**

If I want to migrate SSIS packages,change in dtsconfig alone is enough or I need to use Data tool on packages itself? I am asked to upgrade using only config files which I believe is not possible.I searched on google and all I could find that I need SSDT to upgrade packages.

Kindly provide some insight on my understanding.

I have never worked on SSIS earlier and these days learning SSIS just because I am assigned a task of upgrading SSIS packages. I have around 17 packages for a particular project.

Thanks in advance.

===============================================================

**Old Question:**

Apologies as I can not provide much details as I do not have myself.I am asked to migrate SSIS package configuration from 2005 to SSIS 2017 and just given Config file for 2015 and nothing else.
What all data I should be changing to make it 2017 compliant.
Can someone suggest or pass Config file of those two version so that I can try to figure what changes are required.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming the SSIS project's deployment model is the only thing changing as you move from 2012 to 2017, I am not aware of changes to the configuration file changes that would be required. Test and find out

Comment: This question is too broad.   Try each migration one by one.   If you get a specific error on a specific package, you might be able to word that into an appropriate question.

Comment: @TabAlleman I  updated my question .May be some insight from you people can help me better in understanding.

Comment: @billinkc I have updated the question . Any suggestion to help me in better understanding plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished a project migrating packages from 2008 to 2016.   In the process, we changed the deployment model from "Package", which was the only one available in 2008, to "Project", which became available with version 2012.  When changing deployment models like this, the packages definitely have to be rebuilt individually.   The upgrade wizard helps, but some manual tweaking was required on every package.

If you are going to stay with "Package" deployment and continue to use config files, you might be able to just let the wizard do the upgrade, although you will need to carefully test each package to be sure it worked.  Any packages with Script Tasks or Components are especially likely to need manual intervention.

You can either do a "side-by-side" upgrade, in which case you would need to use the wizard in Visual Studio to upgrade your packages one project at a time, or you can do an "in place" upgrade, in which you simply upgrade your SSIS Server to the new version and let the wizard upgrade all your packages at once.

Either way, the answer to the question you asked is no.  You cannot upgrade to the new version just by changing the config files.

Comment: Either way, the answer to the question you asked is no. You cannot upgrade to the new version just by changing the config files.---Thanks,that a confirmation I was looking for.